# It's only inserting the last value from a textarea

Tags: php, mysql

I'm placing a bunch of emails into a html textarea form. I need to insert the email addresses into my database so I'm using [INSERT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) but for some reason it's only inserting the last value (email). I'm separating the emails with a line break when placing them into the textarea. (*see image below*)

[image: screenshot of textarea containing email addresses]

Also, is it ok to put a sql query inside a loop?

#### Example Emails

- `toku***@att.net`
- `fros***@gmail.com`
- `jpfl***@sbcglobal.net`
- `besc***@msn.com`
- `pgot***@icloud.com`
- `seth***@outlook.com`  *This is the **only** email that gets recorded to the database!*

**Code:**

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]))
{
    if(empty($_POST["email_address"]))
    {
        $error = '<label class="text-danger">Email Address List is required</label>';
    }
    else
    {
        
        $emails = explode(",", $_POST['email_address']);

        foreach($emails as $value)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (username, email)
            VALUES ('beta', '$value')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
            
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is result of `var_dump($_POST['email_address']);` ?

Comment: It's not ok to construct queries via string concatenation. You should use prepared and bound queries instead. The use or otherwise of a loop is a secondary consideration (although much debated)

Comment: @Mario it was outputting string(118) and listing the emails

Comment: @Strawberry thank you :) I will take that into careful thought next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `textarea` then you can do the following:

First Solution:

```
$emails = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['email_address'])); //return an array
```

Second Solution:

```
$emails = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['email_address']);
```

Third Solution:

```
$emails = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['email_address'])));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked like a charmed. Plus I just learned something. I'll accept your answer once it allows me to :)

Comment: Don't forget to bind your values and use [PDO Statments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) to avoid any possible `SQL Injection`